# How to upload a zip file from android through a python lambda to s3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I am trying to send a zip file from an android app to a s3 bucket via a python lambda function, the lambda reads the data and writes into the d3. The zip file on the app is proper but when it reaches the s3 it becomes corrupt and cannot be opened.

The code I have tried so far is below:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)
logger.debug("Event Body{}".format(event['body'].encode('utf-8')))

body =event['body'].encode('utf-8')
fileobj = bytearray(body)
ioobj = io.BytesIO(fileobj)

fileName = date+'/'+'deviceid'
logger.debug('S3 Filename will be {}'.format(fileName))
s3.put_object(Body=ioobj, Bucket='s3_bucket', Key=fileName)
```

Comment: try adding the file extension in the fileName?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, tried adding it no difference, the zip file downloaded from the s3 is still corrupt

Comment: What happens if you `from zipfile import ZipFile` and `ZipFile(event['body'].encode('utf-8')).name_list()`?

Comment: It gives me this `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`